# How do I render this object in React with React Router?

Tags: reactjs

How do I render this object using react router? I want to render this object in a menu.

```
  {main: 'Main', about: 'About', contacts: 'Contacts', '404': 404}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor it this way:

```
const menu = [
  { title: 'Main', path: '/main' },
  { title: 'About', path: '/about' },
  { title: 'Contacts', path: '/contacts' },
  { title: '404', path: '/404' }
];
```

Now do this in your JSX wherever you want your menu:

`{menu.map(item => <Link to={item.path} alt={item.title} />)}`

Don't forget to import `Link`:

`import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'`